# How to evaluate the following integral transform?

Tags: functions

> How to evaluate the following integral:
>
> $$\int \:d^3\:x\:e^{ik_ix^i\:+\:ik_j\left(x-y\right)^j}$$?

Comment: with respect to which variable ??

Comment: Well the integral is over x so x. The thing is I have both x^{i} and x^{j}, this should be some sort of delta function. I tried integrating by parts but I am not quite sure..